# How to enable "pretty" JSON rendering in Mojolicious::Lite?

Tags: perl, mojolicious-lite

Simple question. How do I turn on "pretty" json rendering in Mojolicious::Lite? I'm developing a RESTful API and would like to see my output in a bit more human readable format.

Answer (score 3):

You could override the default JSON renderer in the startup method.

For a minimal example:

```
use JSON::XS;
our $json = JSON::XS->new->utf8->pretty;

sub startup {
  my $self = shift;
  ...
  $self->app->renderer->add_handler(json => sub {
      ${$_[2]} = $json->encode($_[3]{json});
  });
}
```

The default handler is defined in Mojolicious/Renderer.pm and use `Mojo::JSON::encode_json`.

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work, for the record. The renderer didn't seem to change.

This worked: https://gist.github.com/brianmed/3f3e47c1fb9dddd840f3f7e9a17cc53b

Answer (score 2):

[Mojo::JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::JSON) claims to be a minimalistic JSON implementation that is complete to the RFC. It does not implement auto-indentation/making the output pretty.

Your best bet is to use a browser (or other client) that supports that, like [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/). There are browser-plugins like [JSONView for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc).

You can also roll your own client and use one of the JSON implementations, like [JSON::MaybeXS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS).

Then there is also the command line utility `json_pp` that comes with the [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) module. It will by default pretty-print. You can pipe the output of curl to it like this:

```
$ curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ckUMuWrjLS?indent=0 -- | json_pp
```

The `-s` option to curl will silence it's status outputs.

<sub>Source of JSON above: http://www.json-generator.com/</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[JSON::PP](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/JSON/PP#pretty) has `pretty` method.

```
$json->pretty([$enable])
```

Comment: But is Mojolicious::Lite using JSON::PP or Mojo::JSON?

Comment: None but you could use them, right? See an example here: https://gist.github.com/minty/4051592